# Symfony in prod env continue to log in dev.log

Tags: logging, symfony

I have a Symfony3 project with an API.

All users use this API with an url with `app.php` => `prod environment`

I have multiple command like `CRON` or `Process`, each with `--env=prod` at the end.

But when I check my folder `var/logs`, I can see just a `dev.log` with all queries logs like `doctrine.DEBUG:xxxxxx`.

So, why Symfony continue to log in `dev.log` in my prod environement ?

Any ideas ?

Edit : I'm on that because yesterday I had a dev.log file of +- 30go...

Comment: Could you provide whole command-line? Because it seems the ``--env=prod`` is omitted by some reason.

Comment: An example is /usr/bin/php $PATH_PROJECT/bin/console worker:parse:match --env=prod, but actually there is no command running, but my dev.log file continue to grow

Comment: Can you paste your config.yml? Particularly the monolog section.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud you might want to try answer by `nifr` given here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397400/why-does-symfony-still-log-to-a-dev-log-file-even-when-i-didnt-define-it-in-a