# Symfony 2 - Why does event.DEBUG show up in dev.log

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony-2.8

my symfony 2.8 dev.log is flooded with these `event.DEBUG` messages and I don't know how to make it stop. The application is run in a production environment so I'm not even sure why dev.log is being written to.

app/logs/dev.log

```
[2019-10-21 09:53:40] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2019-10-21 09:53:45] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2019-10-21 09:53:45] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
[2019-10-21 09:54:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2019-10-21 09:54:09] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2019-10-21 09:54:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2019-10-21 09:54:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
```

app/config/config_dev.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  fingers_crossed
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: error
            channels: ["!event", "!request"]
```

I've tried explicitly excluding the `event` channel, I've set the log level to `error`, I've set the type from `stream` to `fingers_crossed`, I've even tried removing the `main` handler entirely, but my `dev.log` still gets GB and GB worth of data.

I've also made sure that both prod and dev evironments' cache is cleared using

```
php app/console cache:clear --env={env}
```

How can I stop this?

P.S.
Note that I've read the following posts on SO and the solutions **have not worked** for me:

[event.DEBUG, doctrine.DEBUG, security.DEBUG make dev.log file hugely big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712781/event-debug-doctrine-debug-security-debug-make-dev-log-file-hugely-big)

[Why does Symfony still log to a dev.log file, even when I didn't define it in a loghandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397400/why-does-symfony-still-log-to-a-dev-log-file-even-when-i-didnt-define-it-in-a)

**EDIT**

```
// web/app.php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/global-functions.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Are you sure to be in dev environment ? Seems weird that your log are being written to dev.log

Comment: @DylanKas, I know, it's strange, the application is for sure being run in prod env (app.php, not app_dev.php)

Comment: Can you please show the contents of your `app.php` file?

Comment: @xabbuh, i've included that now

Comment: Can you include some logging or anything similar in `app.php` to make sure this file is actually executed?